# 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I imported a df into Databricks as a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame. Within this df I have 3 columns (which I have verified to be strings) that I wish to concatenate. I have tried to use a simple "+" function first, eg.

```
df["fullname"] = df["firstname"] + df["middlename"] + df["lastname"]
```

But I keep receiving the error "'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment". So I tried to add .astype(str) after every column with no avail. Finally I tried to simply add another column full of the number 5:

```
df['new_col'] = 5
```

and received the same error. So now Im thinking maybe this dataframe is immutable. But I even tried to make a copy of the original df hoping I could modify it

```
df2 = df.select('*')
```

But once again I could not concatenate or modify the new dataframe.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this may just be what you say in the first line of your post, but what do you get when you do `type(df)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the dataframe to a pandas dataframe with [`toPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas). I think the resulting dataframe will be mutable.